# Is it possible to run virtualbox if my CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hardware, cpu, 17.04

How can I run virtualbox on Ubuntu 17.04 if my CPU (I don't exactly know what CPU it is except that it is Intel.) doesn't support hardware virtualization?

I know that my CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization because the following terminal command turned up nothing:

```
grep --color vmx /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: I remember that the option was running a 32bit (i386) linux, since 64bits (amd64) needs hardware virtualization capabilities. Also, if i remember correctly i was able to make it work with 2gb of ram.

Comment: I don't understand. I am running 64bit ubuntu and i am trying to use virtualbox to get windows programs.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've seen some contradicting information, some say yes, most say no however. This is especially true with newer machines, operating systems and versions of VirtualBox.

Below post has a little bit more information, but it basically says the same thing.

[How to run virtual machine when my processor does not support virtualization? | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/726320/how-to-run-virtual-machine-when-my-processor-does-not-support-virtualization)

You might want to include a little bit more about your CPU in general in case some genius out there has come up with a way to do it that will work with your specific system.

Comment: Is my CPU the sticker on my laptop that says "Intel Core 2 Duo"?

Comment: Can you run `cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -m1 "model name"` and include the output? This will tell us the exact CPU. But C2D is probably too old.